# How is the code going to calculate only the wanted value for n?

Tags: vb.net, recursion

I am struggling with this code that I Have to do about calculating the nth term of the Fibonacci series. The program is supposed to take the
value of n and return the corresponding nth Fibonacci number.If the function is given an
invalid n value, it should return -1.

For now, I been trying to make this work, and after 5 hours and 45 minutes sitting on the computer with no ideas how to make this work, here I am asking for help.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Here is what i got so far:

```
Module Module1 

Function Fibonacci(ByVal n)

        If n < 2 Then
            Return n
        Else
            Return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2)
        End If

        If n < 0 Then
            Return Val(-1)
        End If

    End Function

Sub Main()

        Dim n As Double

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome!!!")
        Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter the nth term You Would like to Find ")

        n = Console.ReadLine()

        For n = 1 To 30
            Console.WriteLine(Fibonacci(n))
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: We don't even know what problem you're having.

Comment: give us some input/output or something to tell us where u're having trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1

    Function Fibonacci(ByVal n)
        If n < 2 Then
            Return n
        Else
            Return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2)
        End If
    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim n As Double

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome!!!")
        Console.Write(" Please Enter the nth term You Would like to Find ")

        n = Console.ReadLine()

        If n < 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("-1")
        Else
            For i As Integer = 1 To n
                Console.WriteLine(Fibonacci(i))
            Next
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Module
```